# Understanding types and terms in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax

Which of the types below are the same type:

i. a -> b -> c -> d

ii. (a -> b) -> c -> d

iii. a -> (b -> c) -> d

iv. a -> b -> (c -> d)

v. (a -> b) -> (c -> d)

vi. ((a -> b) -> c) -> d

vii. a -> (b -> (c -> d))

(b) In the following terms what are the types of the functions f given that
x,y,z:: Integer:

i. (f x) (y, z)

ii. f x y z

iii. f (x,y,z)

iv. f (x,(y,z))

(c) Give the types of the following terms (if indeed they type) and indicate which are equal:

i. "abcd"

ii. [(’a’,’b’),(’c’,’d’)]

iii. (’a’:[’b’]):(’c’:[’d’])

iv. ’a’:(’b’:’c’:’d’:[])

v. ["ab","cd"]

I'm not looking for a solution but I need help understanding the usage of () and its meaning.
thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In types, `->` associates to the right, i.e. `a -> b -> c` actually means `a -> (b -> c)`. This is a function which takes an argument of type `a` and returns a function of type `b -> c`.

By comparison, `(a -> b) -> c` is a function which takes as argument a *function* of type `a -> b`, and returns a value of type `c`.

Here are a few examples

```
foo :: Int -> Bool -> String
-- the same as foo :: Int -> (Bool -> String)
-- takes Int, returns function
foo n = \b -> if b && n> 5 then "some result" else "some other result"

bar :: (Int -> Bool) -> String
-- takes function, returns string
bar f = if f 43 then "hello" else "good morning"

-- bar can be called in this way
test :: String
test = bar (\n -> n > 34)    -- evaluates to "hello"
```

When calling a function, as in `f x y z`, application associates to the left, as in `(((f x) y) z)`. For example, these are equivalent:

```
foo 5 True
(foo 5) true
```

By contrast, `(,,,,)` with commas inside is the way to form tuples, and is unrelated to application. Hence, `[(’a’,’b’),(’c’,’d’)]` is a list of pairs. Instead, in your example `(’a’:[’b’]):(’c’:[’d’])` there are no commas, so parentheses are only for grouping, and the expression has the same meaning of

```
x : y
where x = 'a':['b']
      y = 'c':['d']
```

Try thinking about what types should `x` and `y` have, and then think about the type of `x : y`, if any.